# Do you use "pore over"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

As in, *I spent all night poring over those legal documents.*

Or, do you use *pore through*?

Not to be confused with *pour (some sugar)*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poring+over%2C+poring+through&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that *poring through* is *highly* uncommon, whilst *poring over* is common. I have never heard *poring through* before, only *poring over*. Technically, both are correct, but *poring over* is more common.

Comment: Wow, what a great resource.

Comment: Ngram? I recently discovered it via this site, haha. Useful indeed.

Comment: Yes, Ngram...What is Ngram supposed to mean, anyway?

Comment: It needs to be used with caution. It is based only on printed books. As David Crystal writes here <http://david-crystal.blogspot.com/2010/12/on-culturomics.html>, 'We mustn't exaggerate the significance of this project. It is no more than a collection of scanned books - an impressive collection, unprecedented in its size, and capable of displaying innumerable interesting trends, but far away from entire cultural reality.'

Comment: @BarrieEngland This is true. Still useful though.

Comment: @B Seven: [N Gram](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=n+gram&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=Jf6rTsmLFYeT8gO-8NiyCw&ved=0CCYQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=321a4532a0fa7564&biw=1427&bih=897)

Comment: @BarrieEngland - Yes, especially considering that printed books are becoming less and less used while Internet and texting are growing rapidly. It would be interesting to see how much printed books, digital books, Internet and texting contribute to cultural reality over time.

Answer (score 0):

Never. Though I heard a colleague last week say, "I'll pore over those documents tonight." I'm fairly confident he meant *snore* in place of *pore* though.